# How to make the threads in this code to go independently

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I am new to the threads concepts and I try to understand them better. After reading the theory about I decided to write a simple program with threads. I found this (maybe simple) task in the internet:

> Write a program that calculates prime numbers and numbers of Fibunacci
>   on different threads.
>
> a.    The first thread starts searching for prime number from 1, until
>   killing of the program and when a prime number is found the program
>   must present the time for finding this number.
>
> b.    The second thread is calculating and printing numbers of Fibunacci
>   from 1 until killing of the program. When a new number of Fibunacci is
>   found the program prints this number and the time for calculating this
>   number.
>
> c.    The time is shown in ms (milliseconds)
>
> d.    Think about strategies for not having overlapping messages from the
>   console.
>
> e.    The program must work with large as possible numbers. When the
>   number is too large to be held in type like unsigned long long the
>   program stops the calculation of that kind of numbers and shows error
>   message.
>
> Example output:
>
> Prime 1, 0.1 ms.
>
> Fibunacci 1, 0.1 ms.
>
> Prime 2, 0.1 ms.
>
> Fibunacci 2, 0.1 ms.
>
> Prime 3, 0.1 ms.
>
> Fibunacci 3, 0.1 ms.
>
> Fibunacci 5, 0.1 ms.
>
> Prime 5, 0.1 ms.
>
> Fibunacci 8, 0.1 ms.
>
> Prime 7, 0.1 ms.
>
> Fibunacci 13, 0.2 ms.
>
> Fibbunaci 21, 0.1 ms.
>
> Prime 11, 0.2 ms.

This is the code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <string>   // std::cout << std::string
#include <thread>   // std::thread
#include <time.h>   // clock()
#include <mutex> // std::mutex

std::mutex mtx;
int timePrim, timeFib;

bool isPrime(int testedNumber) 
{
    if (testedNumber <= 2) return true;
    if (testedNumber % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; (i*i) <= testedNumber; i += 2) 
    {
        if (testedNumber % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// the function is realized by a recursive algorithm; credits to stackoverflow ;)
bool isFibonacci(unsigned long long testedNumber, int a = 1, int b = 1)
{
    if (testedNumber == 0 || testedNumber == 1)
        return true;//returning true for 0 and 1 right away.
    int nextFib = a + b;//getting the next number in the sequence
    if (nextFib > testedNumber)
        return false;//if we have passed the tested number, it's not in the sequence
    else if (nextFib == testedNumber)
        return true;//if we have a perfect match, the tested number is in the sequence
    else
        isFibonacci(testedNumber, b, nextFib);//otherwise, get the next fibonacci number and repeat.
}

void CheckNumber(unsigned long long numberToCheck, bool ifPrime)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (ifPrime == true) 
    {
        result = isPrime(numberToCheck);
    }
    else
    {
        result = isFibonacci(numberToCheck);
    }
    if (result == true)
    {
        float currentTime = 0;
        std::string typeNumber = "";
        if (ifPrime == true)
        {
            typeNumber = "Prime";
            currentTime = (float)(clock() - timePrim) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            timePrim = clock();
        }
        else
        {
            typeNumber = "Fibonacci";
            currentTime = (float)(clock() - timeFib) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            timeFib = clock();
        }
        mtx.lock();
        std::cout << typeNumber << " number " << numberToCheck << "; time " << currentTime << std::endl;
        mtx.unlock();
    }
}

int main()
{
    timePrim = timeFib = clock();

    for (unsigned long long i = 0; true; i++) // endless for loop == while(true) // by requirements
    {
        std::thread primeThread = std::thread(CheckNumber, i, true);
        std::thread fibThread = std::thread(CheckNumber, i, false);
        primeThread.join();
        fibThread.join();
    }

}
```

As far as I understand, these two threads should go independently one another and to print the results as fast the relevant function find a number. But the results appear straightforward - by the order of the advance of the iterator in the for loop in the main function but not by the time of calculation.
This is a snippet from the console:

> Prime number 0; time 0.005
>
> Fibonacci number 0; time 0.007
>
> Prime number 1; time 0.03
>
> Fibonacci number 1; time 0.029
>
> Prime number 2; time 0.093
>
> Fibonacci number 2; time 0.092
>
> Prime number 3; time 0.023
>
> Fibonacci number 3; time 0.023
>
> Prime number 5; time 0.05
>
> Fibonacci number 5; time 0.052
>
> Prime number 7; time 0.023
>
> Fibonacci number 8; time 0.045
>
> Prime number 11; time 0.038
>
> Prime number 13; time 0.077
>
> Fibonacci number 13; time 0.091
>
> Prime number 17; time 0.019
>
> Prime number 19; time 0.179
>
> Fibonacci number 21; time 0.208
>
> Prime number 23; time 0.027

What should I correct in this code in order to make independent threads running? Where is/are my mistake/s?

// sorry if the text in English above is bad - this is not my native language so it is possible I have made some mistakes...

Comment: How many threads do you intend to have? 2, 3 or infinite?

Comment: join() waits for the thread to finish, so every time round the loop is serialised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your program creates threads for every number `i`, so if you calculate primes and fibonaccis where `i` is from 0 to gazilion, it will create and destroy `2 gazilions` threads. Thread creation requires system calls to be done and it is not particularly fast to do so in a loop.

Also you make both threads wait for each other before submitting more work.

Here is how your program looks in pseudocode (any similarity to real programming languages is purely coincidental):

```
def prime(i):
    calculate one prime

def fibo(i):
    calculate one fibo

for i from 0 to gazilion:
    prime_thread = create_and_run_thread(prime, i)  # expensive, runs gazilion times
    fibo_thread = create_and_run_thread(fibo, i)    # expensive, runs gazilion times

    wait_for(prime_thread)     # wait until single number is crunched
    wait_for(fibo_thread)      # wait until single number is crunched

    destroy_thread(prime_thread)                 
    destroy_thread(fibo_thread)
```

Instead, you could create 2 permanent threads per task and loop separately:

```
def prime():
    for i from 0 to gazilion:
        calculate one prime

def fibo():
    for i from 0 to gazilion:
        calculate one fibo


prime_thread = create_and_run_thread(prime)  # expensive, but runs only once
fibo_thread = create_and_run_thread(fibo)    # expensive, but runs only once

wait_for(prime_thread)     # you only wait until gazilion is reached
wait_for(fibo_thread)      # you only wait until gazilion is reached

destroy_thread(prime_thread)                 # runs oly once
destroy_thread(fibo_thread)                  # runs oly once
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two vectors of `std::thread` objects. One for the Fibonacci calculations, one for the prime number calculations. Then have two loops: One to create both threads and add them to the vectors, and another loop afterwards to join all the threads in the vectors.

While the second loop waits for the first thread to exit, all the threads created in the first loop will run in parallell.

---

What you are doing now is creating two threads, then immediately waiting for them to end before iterating in the loop again. That means only one Fibonacci and one prime number thread will run at a time.